# Is there a simple method to export an input cell?

Tags: export, cells, input

This is a code of an input cell:

```
a = 1 + 5*8;
b = {6, 99};
Entity["MathWorld", "FunctionGraph"]
Plot[x, {x, First[b], Last[b]}]
```

I hope to get a `"expr.svg"` with this content like:

> [image]

This is my [current reimbursement trial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkewZ.png), which seems to be a long way off

Comment: see also [how-to-export-the-cell-above-to-pdf-using-the-export-command-not-using-gui](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207036/how-to-export-the-cell-above-to-pdf-using-the-export-command-not-using-gui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as follows.

First, use the menu item `Evaluation ► Evaluate in Place` in order to convert `Entity["MathWorld", "FunctionGraph"]` to its formatted form.

Second, at the next cell evaluate the following:

```
Export["cell.svg", NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]]]
```

[image: screenshot]

---

**Answer the [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272185/is-there-a-simple-method-to-export-an-input-cell/272187?noredirect=1#comment679884_272187) in the comments:**

> is possible export the all group cell?

Yes, simply export the `CellGroup`:

```
SelectionMove[PreviousCell[], All, CellGroup];
Export["cell.svg", NotebookRead[EvaluationNotebook[]]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why export [such content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTbr7.png) to svg? This is completely without any logic. But it is working fine

Comment: Hi, is possible export the [all group cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQVom.png)?

Comment: @yode I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much...

Comment: I cannot understand still why we can export some `Cell` express into a `.svg` file...

Comment: @yode Because this functionality is implemented, apparently. ;)